# Merging output in table by matching records

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, merge

I have an interesting problem to work in SQL that I really need`enter code here` help with.

What I need to do is to take a table, count the number of repeats/duplicates in a column, add those up and then spit the result out in a new column called "Count" matched to the column that was counted by record.

So, like.. If you had a table like:

```
Domain      | 
----------------
abc.com
abc.com
bca.com
bca.com
bca.com
ggg.com
```

I need it to output something like:

```
Domain     |   Count  
------------------------------
abc.com    |      2
abc.com    |      2
bca.com    |      3
bca.com    |      3
bca.com    |      3
ggg.com    |      1
```

I can get it to count them, but I can't get it to spit it into a new column like that. I'm just not good at iterative regex in SQL.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: This sounds like a `SELECT` - why is it tagged `insert` and `merge`?

Comment: I am trying to do this in Transact SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tbl (Domain nvarchar(max));
insert into tbl values
('abc.com'),
('abc.com'),
('bca.com'),
('bca.com'),
('bca.com'),
('ggg.com');
```

You can use a subquery to count duplicates of each `Domain` and join it with  your main table.

```
select tbl.Domain, t1.cnt
from   tbl
join   (select Domain, count(*) cnt
        from tbl
        group by Domain) t1
on     t1.Domain = tbl.Domain;
```

> ```
> Domain  | cnt
> :------ | --:
> abc.com |   2
> abc.com |   2
> bca.com |   3
> bca.com |   3
> bca.com |   3
> ggg.com |   1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae02e17563fcb62776fdb2bb3ac3c6ef)*